# Linear operator with invariant subspace - Representation wrt to a basis [Kolman, 6.3.12]

Tags: linear-algebra

> A nonempty subspace $S$ of $V$ is called **invariant** under $L$ means : $L(S) \subseteq S$.
>   Let $L: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator with invariant subspace $S.$
>   Show that if $\dim S = m$ and $\dim V = n$, then $L$ has a representation with respect to a basis $\beta$ for $V$ of the form 
>   $\begin{bmatrix}
>         \color{#009900}{A_{m \times m}} & B_{m \times (n - m)} \\
>      \color{#009900}{O_{(n - m) \times m}} & C_{(n - m) \times (n - m)} \\
>        \end{bmatrix}$.
>
> **Answer:** Since $\dim S = m$ is given, let $\beta = \{\mathbf{v_i}\}_{1 \le i \le m}$ be an ordered basis for $S$.
>   Since any lin-ind subset of a vector space can be extended to a basis for this same vector space proper (Basis Extension Theorem),
>   thus $T = \{\mathbf{v_i, v_{m + 1}, \cdots, v_n}\}_{1 \le i \le m}$ is an ordered basis for $V$.
>   Since  $L(S) \subseteq S$, thus $\forall \; 1 \le j \le m, \; L(\mathbf{v_j}) \in S$.
>   $\Longrightarrow L(\mathbf{v_j}) = \sum\limits_{1 \le j \le m}a_j\mathbf{v_j} + \sum\limits_{(m+1) \le k \le n}0\mathbf{v_k} $.
>   $\Longrightarrow [L(\mathbf{v_j})]_T = \begin{bmatrix}
>     a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_m & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
>     \end{bmatrix}^T$.

The above $[L(\mathbf{v_j})]_T$ holds for $\forall \; 1 \le j \le m$, so it describes only $\color{#009900}{\text{the first $m$ columns of the matrix representation}}$? What about submatrices $B, C$?

Source: P398, 6.3.12, *Elementary Linear Algebra* by Kolman. WARNING: Book's odiously vile.

---

**Supplementary dated Sep 12 2013 :**

Doesn't the solution prove that the matrix representation of $L$ is only  $\begin{bmatrix}
        \color{#009900}{A_{m \times m}} \\ \color{#009900}{O_{(On - m) \times m}}  \\
       \end{bmatrix}$? Despite our apathy towards $B,C$, mustn't we conclude with $\begin{bmatrix}
        \color{#009900}{A_{m \times m}} & B_{m \times (n - m)} \\ \color{#009900}{O_{(n - m) \times m}} & C_{(n - m) \times (n - m)} \\
       \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: If you would like a well-written free resource, I suggest http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html

Comment: @Potato: Many thanks. I'll pore over it.

Comment: Incidentally, I've retained the warning about this book because I want to stress that I referenced this book only for citing this question. I'd be afflicted if someone uses it after reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the proof describes only the first $m$ columns. This is all that is necessary. The goal is to find a matrix representation where the lower $(n-m)\times m$ corner vanishes. To verify this property, we only need to consider the first $m$ columns. We don't care what $A,B,C$ are.

Regarding your edit, we know from the problem statement $L$ is an operator from an $n$-dimensional vector space to itself, so it must be an $n\times n$ matrix (after we fix a basis). We can partition any $n\times n$ matrix into the following form (I have violated alphabetical order to conform with the problem statement)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        {A_{m \times m}} & B_{m \times (n - m)} \\ {D_{(n - m) \times m}} & C_{(n - m) \times (n - m)} \\
       \end{bmatrix}.$$

Think of taking a $n\times n$ matrix and drawing a vertical line after the $m$th column and a horizontal line after the $m$th row. This gives you $4$ block matrices (here $A,B,C,D$).

Your problem asks us to show that if we fix a basis for $V$ as stipulated in the problem statement, then $D$ is the zero matrix $O$. To show this, we must only examine the first $m$ columns, since $D$ is contained in the first $m$ columns.

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. I'm still irresolute over the solution so added a supplementary in my OP. I'd be grateful for your answer to it.

Comment: @LePressentiment Please see my edits.

Comment: I express my gratitude to your continued, speedy help profoundly. I desire to upvote more than once here but can't so will do so for your other posts.

Comment: @LePressentiment Thanks. Good luck with your studies.